# Ubuntu Mate 20.04 - switched o Wayland UI and unable to restore initial Mate UI configuration

Tags: gnome, 20.04, mate

because of my curiosity, I've decided to check Ubuntu on Wayland UI. That was a huge mistake.

I've lost: 1) Mate login screen, which looks like in gnome and 2) Notifications became un-clickable and look like in gnome. They became blurry when I hover them and I'm clicking through them but can't click them to bring the app related to it to the front.

I've tried removing gdm3, that was also a mistake I was unable to start Mate. I've seen in the boot logs that ubuntu is unable to start lightdm and unable to find my GPU (I'm on Intel/Nvidia - prime). I managed to log-in and install gdm3 back using recovery console.

Can I somehow bring my Mate UI back to the state before I switched to Gnome? The layout can be reset, I don't mind, I can set it again... all I want to have is my Mate UI :)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi user007, I understood correctly, that these issues persist after you have switched back to X11/Xorg, right? If so, you could try to reinstall the Mate desktop. Purge the package `ubuntu-mate-desktop`, do an `apt autoremove` and reinstall the `ubuntu-mate-desktop`. I haven't tried this, but I'd proceed that way. To be safe, make sure you have a backup of your data.

Comment: Hi, @Béné. yes the issue persists despite I've switched to Mate UI and lightdm. I was thinking about removing and installing mate again, but.. how safe is that?

Comment: Removing and re-installing Mate would very probably fix the issue. It should be reasonably straight forward, however, I'd make sure to have a backup of my data and a USB drive with Ubuntu / Ubuntu Mate handy. That way you can easily reinstall without stressing about data loss.

Comment: @user007 You can post this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @mchid sure, will do shortly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue has been resolved now.
Obviously I've reinstalled all packages mentioned in the post above as well. However, it did not help. So I've started digging how the config for greeter and notifications should look like.

I've checked what kind of notification services I have by running:

```
grep -r org.freedesktop.Notifications /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
```

that gave me:

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.mate.Notifications.service:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

So I've disabled the first one by running:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disable
```

In addition, I've checked my lightdm config by running:

```
lightdm --show-config
```

that gave me:

```
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
user-session=<can't remember now what was there>
```

I've changed that to:

```
greeter-session=slick-greeter
user-session=mate
```

I've restarted my laptop after doing that. Since now both the greeter and notifications work again.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following commands to make sure all the correct packages are installed and this will hopefully change back some of your settings (like the notifications on the Mate desktop) by reinstalling the Mate desktop, notification daemon, and other settings related packages without uninstalling anything:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-default-settings ubuntu-mate-lightdm-theme ubuntu-mate-core mate-notification-daemon ubuntu-mate-desktop ubuntu-mate-welcome
```

A reboot may be needed to apply some of the changes.

---

Next, you don't have to uninstall GDM. You can switch back to lightdm by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Use the arrow keys to select lightdm and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Next, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to a TTY screen and log on with your username and password. Then, run the following commands to start lightdm:

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

This should restart a login screen automatically or you can manually switch to the lighdm screen by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> after lightdm starts.

<sub>**Note: unlike lightdm, GDM usually runs on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>**</sub>

Also, just in case you were't aware, you can select the Mate desktop on the GDM or Lightdm login screen.

There is usually a cog wheel you can click somewhere on the login screen (or sometimes on the status bar) that will give you a selection of desktops such as, Gnome, Gnome (Wayland), and Mate.

---

As for Nvidia, recovery mode won't use Nvidia drivers so this may be the reason for the errors in recovery mode.

However, sometimes a kernel update can leave you without drivers after a reboot if they aren't installed properly. Whatever the case may be, the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` will ensure the drivers are properly installed.

---

**EDIT**

If all else fails, the following will completely reinstall the full `ubuntu-mate-desktop` and most related dependency packages without uninstalling anything:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall compiz-mate compton deja-dup deja-dup-caja duplicity engrampa gir1.2-caja-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-mate-panel gir1.2-matedesktop-2.0 gir1.2-matepanelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-pluma-1.0 gtkhash gufw ideviceinstaller libimobiledevice-utils libmarco-private1 libmate-desktop-2-17 libmate-menu2 libmate-panel-applet-4-1 libmate-sensors-applet-plugin0 libmate-slab0 libmate-window-settings1 libmatedict6 libmatekbd-common libmatekbd4 libmatemixer-common libmatemixer0 libmateweather-common libmateweather1 mate-accessibility-profiles mate-applet-appmenu mate-applet-brisk-menu mate-applets mate-applets-common mate-calc mate-calc-common mate-control-center mate-control-center-common mate-desktop mate-desktop-common mate-desktop-environment-core mate-dock-applet mate-hud mate-icon-theme mate-indicator-applet mate-indicator-applet-common mate-media mate-media-common mate-menu mate-menus mate-netbook mate-netbook-common mate-notification-daemon-common mate-optimus mate-panel mate-panel-common mate-polkit mate-polkit-common mate-power-manager mate-power-manager-common mate-screensaver mate-screensaver-common mate-sensors-applet mate-sensors-applet-common mate-session-manager mate-settings-daemon mate-settings-daemon-common mate-system-monitor mate-system-monitor-common mate-terminal mate-terminal-common mate-themes mate-tweak mate-user-guide mate-utils mate-utils-common mate-window-applets-common mate-window-buttons-applet mate-window-menu-applet mate-window-title-applet menu-xdg mozo pluma pluma-common plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-text python-caja python-caja-common python-fasteners python-ldb python-lockfile python-mate-menu ubuntu-mate-artwork ubuntu-mate-guide ubuntu-mate-icon-themes ubuntu-mate-themes ubuntu-mate-wallpapers ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-bionic ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-common ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-photos mate-desktop-environment software-center synaptic rss-glx mate-sensors-applet-nvidia indicator-sounds libplank-doc python-lockfile-doc mate-notification-daemon ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-default-settings ubuntu-mate-desktop ubuntu-mate-lightdm-theme ubuntu-mate-welcome
```

I compiled this list on 18.04 so if you get a "package not found" error, simply remove the package from the list and run again.

Comment: Thank you @mchid for your response. However, it did not help :( 
Login screen and notifications are still Gnome-Like. Maybe the gnome login screen has a higher priority so shown on always first despite other exists? I can live with such login screen. I need notifications more, they are simply unusable now. :(  
One thing is a bit worse now. Seems it broke the login somehow. My user is selected by default on login screen - when I don't touch the dropdown the login fails, even if I provide correct password. However, when I select something else and then select my user I can login.

Comment: @user007 Check the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.mate.Notifications.service:` and it should only have one line: `Exec=/usr/lib/mate-notification-daemon/mate-notification-daemon`. Also, to change your login screen back to the MATE version, run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` then select `lightdm` and then reboot.

Comment: @user007 The login screen priority is set by the user when you run the `dpkg-reconfigure` command. Also, GDM is known to have problems logging in and switching back to `lightdm` usually fixes that issue. If you have done this, please provide the errors.

Comment: @user007 Also, If I understand you correctly, you can login to a Gnome or Wayland session but you can't login to Mate? If this is the case, it may be that you need to fix your `.Xauthority` file like this `sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.Xauthority` and then reboot.

Comment: thank you @mchid. A little progress here. I managed to bring origin greeter back by updating lightdm properties "greeter-session=slick-greeter" it was set to lightdm-gtk-greeter. However, it's broken in some strange way. I can see two password input boxes there :)  I can log in when I put my pass into the second one :D I'm going to check your advice from your earlier comment. I'll let you know shortly how it goes.

Comment: So ... the notifications stopped working completely now. I've removed other lines from org.freedesktop.mate.Notifications.service file, so it contains "[D-BUS Service]" section name and the Exec you provided above.

Comment: OK.... fixed that. I'll update my question :) thank you again @mchid!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by selecting `lightdm` (instead of `gdm3`) in `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`. My `lightdm --show-config` shows `greeter-session=slick-greeter`, but continues to show `user-session=ubuntu`. I can't say what changing it to `mate` would do because I can't figure out how to change this.